# boto3 get all keys in filtered bucket as a list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'd like to get all keys in a "subfolder" in an s3 bucket, and put these keys into a list so that I can use the list for multiprocessing the files on s3. My current approach is below, and takes about 5 minutes for a "subfolder" that has ~800,000 items in it. Is there a quicker way of accomplishing this?

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
mybucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name')

ls_keys = []
for obj in mybucket.objects.filter(Prefix='foo/bar'):
    ls_keys.append(obj.key)
```

Comment: Have you tried S3 batch?

Comment: If you don't need the list guaranteed to be current then you can use S3 Inventory reports.

Comment: [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.